# Awk command to add and delete lines from a block

Tags: shell, awk

my input file has blocks like

```
[abc]  
para1=123  
para2=456  
para3=111  
para4=666

[pqr]  
para1=333    
para2=765    
para3=1345    

[xyz]    
para1=888    
para2=236
```

I have two requirements:

1. Add a line to a block, ex: add ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`para4=uiy` to block `[pqr]`
2. To delete a parameter from a block, ex: delete `para2=236` from block `[xyz]`

Please help me how can I achieve this with awk command

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use awk for this? It sound more appropriate to use a programming language to accomplish this task.

Comment: did you got any idea from your previous questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484795/sed-or-awk-to-replace-a-line-in-a-block , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609106/sed-or-awk-to-delete-a-block , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649733/awk-command-to-add-and-delete-lines-from-a-block

Comment: If yes, then post the command you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Add a param

```
awk -F"\n" '$1~/pqr/{$(NF+1)="para4=uiy"}1' OFS="\n" RS= file
```

If it always adds the last one and you dont know the number you could use

```
awk -F"\n" '$1~/pqr/{$(NF+1)="para"NF"=uiy"}1' OFS="\n" RS=
```

Remove a param

```
awk -F"\n" '$1~/xyz/{gsub(/\npara2=236/,"")}1' OFS="\n" RS= file
```

Comment: You should add `ORS="\n\n"` to preserve space between blocks.  And I guess he does not know the value of `para2` but like to remove the line anyway.  And since its one hit, you should use `sub` not `gsub`

Comment: He doesn't specify if it is one, so this would remove all matches in the block if there are multiple, and only one if there is one, not really any negative effect to using `gsub`. Also i meant to put that `ORS` but i forgot :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.  By setting `RS` to nothing, `awk` works with blocks. (OSCam?)

```
awk '/^\[pqr/ {$0=$0"\npara4=uiy"} /^\[xyz/ {sub(/para2=[0-9]*/,"")}1' RS= ORS="\n\n" file
[abc]
para1=123
para2=456
para3=111
para4=666

[pqr]
para1=333
para2=765
para3=1345
para4=uiy

[xyz]
para1=888
```